# Calling getProperty on a Properties instance is returning null instead of value

Tags: java, properties, getproperty

Why is the code below returning `null`, instead of `true`?

I can see that the property is being set based on the `{TEST=true}` output.

Java code:

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("TEST", true);
        System.out.println(props);
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("TEST"));
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
1
{TEST=true}
null
2
```

Comment: Use setProperty() instead of put().  getProperty() and setProperty() operate on Strings.  See the JavaDoc, here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setProperty()` instead of `put()`.  `getProperty()` and `setProperty()` operate on Strings.  See the JavaDoc, here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

If you look at the source code for the `Properties` class, you should see that it does an `instanceof` check on the value of the property that it retrieves in `getProperty()`.  If the property value is not a String, it returns `null`.

Comment: While everything you’ve said is true, people should not decide how to use methods based on source code.  Method implementations are private and may change from one release to another.  What is stable and will never change is the contract of the method, that is, its javadoc.

Comment: Fair comment - I'm definitely not advocating that anyone look at source code rather than public API's to make decisions.  The only reason I cited the source is because the JavaDoc isn't particularly clear on this behaviour - so it simply answers the OP's original "why does this happen?" question.

Answer (score 1):

The `put` method you use is taken from `HashTable` which `Properties` class is extending.
If you want to use `put` then to retrieve it you should use `get` :

```
props.get("TEST");
```

However as mentioned in the comments, for setting properties you should be using `setProperty()` method instead :

```
props.setProperty("TEST", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods
>   can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly
>   discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or
>   values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead.
>   If the store or save method is called on a "compromised" Properties
>   object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail.
>   Similarly, the call to the propertyNames or list method will fail if
>   it is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a
>   non-String key.

So for String use setProperty() and getProperty() method and for Object use put() and get() method.